Como usar la API de windows hello?
Hola he estado investigando un poco acerca de como usar el sensor dactilar que viene en algunas laptops como método de autenticación en sistemas que estemos desarrollando.
Asi que revisando en la pagina de Microsoft encontré este proyecto donde nos enseñan a implementar Windows Hello por medio de un ejemplo, en nuestros sistemas. Nunca he usado una API pero me llama mucho la atención aprender sobre esta tecnología.
La información acerca del proyecto esta en la siguiente Imagen:

Las instrucciones para usar el ejemplo son estas:

Esto es lo que contiene la carpeta al descomprimirse:

Después de abrir el archivo .sln el contenido es este: 
Posteriormente siguiendo las instrucciones presiono control + shift + b para compilarlo. Y luego F5 para Depurarlo.
Lo que provoca que el servidor inicie:

Mi duda comienza en este punto ya que las instrucciones dicen que debo crear una nueva instanca de Visual Studio, es decir, que abra una nueva ventana de visual studio y ejecute el archivo .sln
Esto me confunde por que no se si se refiera al mismo del servidor o a que archivo. En pocas plabra es aqui donde me enredo y no se como proceder.
Agradezco la correcion a mi pregunta y espero con paciencia una respuesta. Muchas Gracias por leerme.

No entendi absolutamente nada de tu problema, y las imagenes ayudan menos todavia.. un archivo sln es una solucion, un conjunto de projectos en codigo fuente... no se a que te referis con depurar el sln... no se bien que estas ejecutando o donde... por favor, aclara muchisimo mas tu problema...

Hola. Muchas Gracias por responder. Bueno por lo que leí, se trata de un conjunto de programas que permiten poder usar la API de windows Hello. Corrígeme si no es correcto.  Las instrucciones para poder usarlo están en el archivo readme. Lo adjuntare en mi pregunta.  Lamento que mi pregunta haya sido confusa.

No se de donde abras sacado el ejemplo pero con una busqueda rápida encontré la documentación para implementar un inicio de sesión paso a paso Windows Hello - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn, incluso más arriba tiene un apartado de biometría de huellas digitales. No entiendo bien para que quieres usar el ejemplo.

Quiero Aprender como usar la Api y me interesa como almacenar la biometria de las huellas en una base de datos. Aunque creo que primero debo aprender a usar visual studio, hoy aprendi mucho. Crei que era similar a visual studio code. Es todo un mundo lo de .Net Gracias por compartir el link, ya lo habia revisado pero aun no sabia como ejecutar los codigos. Ya estoy instalando los paquetes que necesito.
